Error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol when linking to Oracle SDK
I'm trying to extend the DuckDB extension template to connect to Oracle
I've downloaded the Oracle SDK and configured CMakesLists.txt :
# Specify the path to the Oracle Instant Client
set(ORACLE_INSTANT_CLIENT_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/src/instantclient_23_4")

# Add include directories
include_directories(${ORACLE_INSTANT_CLIENT_DIR}/sdk/include)

# Find the OCCI and OCI libraries
find_library(OCI_LIB oci PATHS ${ORACLE_INSTANT_CLIENT_DIR}/sdk/lib)


if(NOT OCI_LIB)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "oci.lib not found in ${ORACLE_INSTANT_CLIENT_DIR}/sdk/lib")
endif()

# Link the libraries
target_link_libraries(${EXTENSION_NAME} ${OCI_LIB})

I modified the template entry point to connect:
#include <occi.h>
// ...
    inline void OracleScannerScalarFun(DataChunk &args, ExpressionState &state, Vector &result)
    {
        auto &user_vector = args.data[0];
        auto &password_vector = args.data[1];
        auto &db_vector = args.data[2];
        auto &query_vector = args.data[3];

        oracle::occi::Environment *env = oracle::occi::Environment::createEnvironment(oracle::occi::Environment::DEFAULT);
        oracle::occi::Connection *conn = env->createConnection(user_vector.ToString(), password_vector.ToString(), db_vector.ToString());

        UnaryExecutor::Execute<string_t, string_t>(
            user_vector, result, args.size(),
            [&](string_t name)
            {
                return StringVector::AddString(result, "ok");
                ;
            });
    }

Building returns a linker error:
oracle_scanner_extension.lib(oracle_scanner_extension.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external sym
bol "public: static class oracle::occi::Environment * __cdecl oracle::occi::Environment::createEnvi
ronment(enum oracle::occi::Environment::Mode,void *,void * (__cdecl*)(void *,unsigned __int64),void
 * (__cdecl*)(void *,void *,unsigned __int64),void (__cdecl*)(void *,void *))" (?createEnvironment@
Environment@occi@oracle@@SAPEAV123@W4Mode@123@PEAXP6APEAX1_K@ZP6APEAX112@ZP6AX11@Z@Z) referenced in
 function "void __cdecl duckdb::OracleScannerScalarFun(class duckdb::DataChunk &,struct duckdb::Exp
ressionState &,class duckdb::Vector &)" (?OracleScannerScalarFun@duckdb@@YAXAEAVDataChunk@1@AEAUExp
ressionState@1@AEAVVector@1@@Z) [G:\projects\oracle_scanner\build\release\extension\parquet\parquet
_loadable_extension.vcxproj]
G:\projects\oracle_scanner\build\release\extension\parquet\parquet.duckdb_extension : fatal error L
NK1120: 1 unresolved externals [G:\projects\oracle_scanner\build\release\extension\parquet\parquet_
loadable_extension.vcxproj]

What else must I do to link the oracle SDK, besides the CMakeLists.txt?

The code is not C, don't tag C a C++ code.

Please post the errors in a code block to keep their format.

Was the oracle library built with the same compiler and runtime settings as your application?

Looks like you need to link to oraocci23.lib,  oci.lib only contains the c apis

I'm using the SDK from instantclient-sdk-windows.x64-23.4.0.24.05.zip. I tried linking oraocci23.lib find_library(OCCI oraocci23), but cmake always fails to find it. I did GLOB LIB_FILES and the .lib exists, but it keeps failing with a oraocci23.lib not found

If I link the absolute path to the oracocci23.lib it builds successfully. Does find_library(OCCI oraocci23) have to match the oraocci23.lib filename, or some internal name when the .lib was built?
